# Packer Ubuntu 20.04 autoinstall via CD drive

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, packer, ubuntu-20.04

I configured my Ubuntu 20.04.1 Packer Template Deployment with user-data and meta-data mounted over CD, but I don't know how to configure the autoinstall bootcommand to get the subiquity part working:

ubuntu-20.04.json

```
"cd_files": ["{{template_dir}}/ubuntu-20.04/meta-data", "{{template_dir}}/ubuntu-20.04/user-data"],
    "cd_label": "cidata",
    
    "iso_paths": [
      "[ColoNord-ISOs] ISOs/ubuntu-20.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso"
    ],
    "boot_wait": "5s",
    "floppy_files": ["{{template_dir}}/preseed.cfg"],
    "boot_command": [
      "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
      "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
      "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
      "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
      "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
      "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
      "<wait><esc><wait><f6><wait><esc><wait>",
      "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
      "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
      "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
      "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
      "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
      "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
      "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
      "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
      "<bs><bs><bs>",
      "/casper/vmlinuz ",
      "initrd=/casper/initrd ",
      " ipv6.disable=1 autoinstall ",
      "ds=nocloud-net;s=/cidata/",
      "<enter>"
    ]
```

user-data

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
    version: 1
    early-commands:
        #Stop SSH to prevent Packer from connecting too early
        - sudo systemctl stop ssh
    apt:
    geoip: true
    preserve_sources_list: false
    primary:
    - arches: [amd64, i386]
        uri: http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
    - arches: [default]
        uri: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports
    identity:
    hostname: ubuntu2004
    username: username
    password: password
    ssh:
    allow-pw: true
    install-server: true
    locale: de_CH
    keyboard: 
    layout: gb
    network:
        network:
            version: 2
            ethernets:
            ens160:
                addresses:
                - 10.0.249.75/24
                gateway4: 10.0.249.1
                nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 10.10.10.10
                - 10.10.10.11
                - 10.10.10.12
                - 10.10.10.13
                search:
                - domain.local

    storage:
    layout:
        name: direct
    config:
        - type: disk
        id: disk0
        match:
            size: largest
        - type: partition
        id: boot-partition
        device: disk0
        size: 500M
        - type: partition
        id: root-partition
        device: disk0
        size: -1
    late-commands:
    - "echo 'Defaults:username !requiretty' > /target/etc/sudoers.d/username"
    - "echo 'username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL' >> /target/etc/sudoers.d/username"
    - "chmod 440 /target/etc/sudoers.d/username"
```

Would be awesome to get this working, so I can finally deploy some basic installed vSphere Ubuntu VM Templates.
I don't find that much documentation about this stuff, so if you can handle me sth to get this solved would also be great.

Greez.

Answer (score 0):

I use the default HTTP source that packer sets up rather than CD, but the boot_command should be similar.

From [Automating Ubuntu 20.04 installs with Packer](https://nickcharlton.net/posts/automating-ubuntu-2004-installs-with-packer.html)

```
 "boot_command": [
        "<enter><enter><f6><esc><wait> ",
        "autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;s=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/",
        "<enter>"
      ]
```

If you want to use CD, then the only difference with this part should be the source for the cloud-config.

I have a working packer setup with Ubuntu 20.04 and the subiquity installer still awaiting a PR on the [boxcutter/ubuntu](https://github.com/boxcutter/ubuntu/pull/195) github repo.  You could refer to that for help.  It took me awhile to figure out as well.

Comment: yeah i see, but the problem is still, that my packer instance is running in a gitlab runner docker container, which got it's own private docker network. and i can't expose the packer port through the container.
so can you tell me what i have to put behind s= for the path to the CD mount?